# c++ program for encryption and decryption

Tags: c++, encryption

When I tried using this code template and encrypt a block consisting of some null characters , its execution got aborted. When I used debugger and saw the cause of failure, I got to know that when null characters get appended, the execution aborts.

Can anyone suggest me solutions in c++ to decrypt successfully even when I encounter a null charater which is significant and has to be decrypted.?

Comment: One simple way would be to base64 encode the data before encrypting it and base64 decode it after decrypting it. You could convert it into a hex string as well, converting nul to "00". Alternatively, just use any other encryption code that handles raw data -- most do.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string#size` determines the size by looking for a `null` character, i.e. a byte valued zero. You'd be better off using `std::vector` or a better way of determining the size.

---

If you want to store the ciphertext as readable (printable) text then use an encoding such as base 64 or hexadecimals. For storing in binary files or binary streams this is not necessary as long as handle the input / output as binary.

---

Note that ECB mode is not secure for most purposes. You'd need to use CBC with a random IV or, if possible, an authenticated mode such as GCM with a unique IV per key.